# Problem with the customer groups after importing the magento csv customer data

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer

I need help about a problem I met after importing my customers data in Magento.

I imported the data via csv to a new magento in order to create a new website,
but I met a problem concerning the customer groups.

I cannot find the reason why but for some customers account, after saving their data, they are changed from the "domestic market customer group" to the "overseas customer group".

From what I was able to check, It seems there is nothing in common between the customer accounts that are changed from one group to another.

Would anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Customer address involve.

System will change customer group base on the vat information from your customer address, include empty value or real value.

About detail, You can hack to code in `Mage_Customer_Model_Observer::afterAddressSave` by yourself.

In your case, you can try to add field `"disable_auto_group_change"` with value 1 in your csv file.